# How to access Child Class members in Parent class in Python

Tags: python, oop

Short version: For normal Object members, this is simple - you just use `self.member` in the parent, and the child can override the member and everything is happily object orientated.  But what about class members that may get overriden by a child class?

To make that clear:
I know in Python I can just give `Classname.membername` but how do I allow Class members to be overriden?  For example I have

```py
class BaseDB:
    user_table = "users"
    
    # Class member function
    def make_sql():
        return f'SELECT * from {BaseDB.user_table};'

    # Boilerplate functions that use "user_table"
    def load_users(self):
        return db.connection.cursor.execute(BaseDB.make_sql())


class SomeDatabase(BaseDB):
    user_table = "the_users_table"
    
# Somewhere else in the code....
dbwrapper = SomeDatabase()
dbwrapper.load_users()  # This does not use the overwridden value in SomeDatabase, it uses the value form the parent class
```

What I'm looking for something like `self`, but for the Class, not for the object.

At first I thought I could try and use `type(self).class_member` .... Not sure if that would even work, but `self` might not be available, eg in a non-class member method.

My workaround at present is to use normal object members - right now I don't have a requirement to access these from a class method.  The only reason why I want to make these into Class members is because the values are constant for the class, not the object.

Edit:  Added the somewhat contrived Class member function `make_sql` and used it in the normal member function.

Note: The derived class only sets the class member - Nothing else is overridden.

Note #2 - This is not a major obstacle.  If there is a solution, I am sure I can use it ... if not, I've been getting along without it fine, so I'm just asking to find out if I'm missing out on something.

EDIT #2:
I just thought I should put the code into my IDE and see if I had any errors (I'm lazy).  The IDE told me I need to have a "self" on the class member so I annotated it with `@classmember`.  The IDE told me "Well then you should have a `cls` parameter.  VOILA!  This solves the problem, of course.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: `cls.user_table` in a classmethod or `self.user_table` in a regular instance method will return the overridden attribute. Can you give examples of where you are having an issue?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking... you *are* overriding the class member `user_table` in your subclass.

Comment: I will update the question

Comment: Please see the update.  Does that explain the problem?